# Comparing t-SNE solutions using their Kullback-Leibler divergences

Tags: data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I am trying to optimize the `perplexity` parameter of t-SNE in order to better understand the degree of separability of various data sets. 
Kullback-Leibler divergences of t-SNE solutions are directly comparable between runs **when perplexity remains fixed** as mentioned in the author's FAQ:

> if you use the same data and perplexity, you can compare the
>   Kullback-Leibler divergences that t-SNE reports. It is perfectly fine
>   to run t-SNE ten times, and select the solution with the lowest KL
>   divergence

[Link here](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/)

My question is whether it's appropriate and useful to directly compare the KL
divergences between runs but using **different perplexities.**  I would then just select the solution with the lowest KL divergence

[this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123040/whats-wrong-with-t-sne-vs-pca-for-dimensional-reduction-using-r?rq=1#comment464300_123040) to another question mentions:

> tSNE has a theoretical optimum perplexity that minimizes the KL
>   divergence between your data in its original and projected dimensions

Is comparing KL between runs with different perplexities a good way to find that "theoretical optimum perplexity?"

Comment: Welcome to the community dir!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, no; comparing the optimality of a perplexity parameter through the correspond $KL(P||Q)$ divergence is not a valid approach. As I explained in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245168): "*The perplexity parameter increases monotonically with the variance of the Gaussian used to calculate the distances/probabilities $P$. Therefore as you increase the perplexity parameter as a whole you will get smaller distances in absolute terms and subsequent KL-divergence values.*" This is described in detail in the original 2008 JMLR paper of [Visualizing Data using $t$-SNE](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/publications/papers/JMLR_2008.pdf) by Van der Maaten and Hinton.

You can easily see this programmatically with a toy dataset too. Say for example you want to use $t$-SNE for the famous [iris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) dataset and you try different perplexities eg. $10, 20, 30, 40$. What would be emperical distribution of the scores? Well, we are lazy so let's get the computer do the job for us and run the `Rtsne` routine with a few ($50$) different starting values and see what we get:
(*Note: I use the [Barnes-Hut implementation of $t$-SNE (van der Maaten, 2014)](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/publications/papers/JMLR_2014.pdf) but the behaviour is the same*.)

```
library(Rtsne)
REPS =  50; # Number of random starts

per10 <- sapply(1:REPS, function(u) {set.seed(u); 
       Rtsne(iris, perplexity = 10, check_duplicates= FALSE)}, simplify = FALSE)
per20 <- sapply(1:REPS, function(u) {set.seed(u); 
       Rtsne(iris, perplexity = 20, check_duplicates= FALSE)}, simplify = FALSE)
per30 <- sapply(1:REPS, function(u) {set.seed(u); 
       Rtsne(iris, perplexity = 30, check_duplicates= FALSE)}, simplify = FALSE)
per40 <- sapply(1:REPS, function(u) {set.seed(u); 
       Rtsne(iris, perplexity = 40, check_duplicates= FALSE)}, simplify = FALSE)

costs <- c( sapply(per10, function(u) min(u$itercosts)), 
            sapply(per20, function(u) min(u$itercosts)),
            sapply(per30, function(u) min(u$itercosts)), 
            sapply(per40, function(u) min(u$itercosts)))
perplexities <- c( rep(10,REPS), rep(20,REPS), rep(30,REPS), rep(40,REPS))

plot(density(costs[perplexities == 10]), xlim= c(0,0.3), ylim=c(0,250), lwd= 2,
     main='KL scores from difference perplexities on the same dataset'); grid()
lines(density(costs[perplexities == 20]), col='red', lwd= 2); 
lines(density(costs[perplexities == 30]), col='blue', lwd= 2)
lines(density(costs[perplexities == 40]), col='magenta', lwd= 2);
legend('topright', col=c('black','red','blue','magenta'), 
       c('perp.  = 10', 'perp.  = 20', 'perp.  = 30','perp.  = 40'), lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Looking at the picture it is clear that the smaller perplexity values correspond to higher $KL$ scores as expected based on the reading of the original paper above. Using the $KL$ scores to pick the optimal perplexity is not very helpful. You can still use it to pick the optimal run for a given solution though!

Comment: Thank you! Great illustration and the quote from your other answer says it all. I appreciate it.

Comment: Cool, I am glad I could help!